# Restrict mysql db access to only particular user

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

Well, we all know that we can restrict few users from accessing certain databases or tables in mysql by using the `GRANT PRIVILEGES` command. What my question is, whether it is possible to create a database and make sure that it can only be accessed by my created new user only and not even by the root user.

So the scenario should be like:

```
 Root/ admin User --------> Creates a new user
 Someone i.e root/ new user --------------> Creates a database with few tables
 That database should only be accessed by the new user and no other user. 
 Even root user should not have rights to access that db or the tables within.
```

How can this be possible or whether this is possible or not?

Comment: create newuser by root. give ALL or star.star privileges to newuser. then newuser creates the db and tables. In that case?

Comment: not possible if you create a user and give the new user privileges the user (root) should have privileges to that database. Its in the manual “To use GRANT, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are granting.“ source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-overview.. Besides you should not mess with the default privileges of the root user